# Show $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}e^{\frac{B_t^2(1+t)}{2}}$ is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

> Show that for some Brownian Motion $B_t$, that the following is a martingale $$Y_t =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}e^{\frac{B_t^2(1+t)}{2}}$$

I want to therefore show that $\mathbb{E}(Y_t|\mathcal{F}_s) = Y_s. $

\begin{align} E[Y_t|\mathcal F_s]&=  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+t}}E[e^{B_t^2(1+t)}|\mathcal F_s] \\
\end{align}
Then consider
\begin{align}
E[e^{cB_t^2}|\mathcal F_s]&=E[\exp(c(B_s + B_t - B_s)^2)|\mathcal F_s]\\
&= E[\exp\left({cB_s}^2 + 2cB_s(B_t - B_s) + c(B_t - B_s)^2\right)|\mathcal F_s]
\\& = E[e^{c{B_s}^2}|\mathcal F_s] \times E[\exp(2cB_s(B_t - B_s))|\mathcal F_s] \times E[e^{c(B_t - B_s)^2}|\mathcal F_s] \\&= e^{c{B_s}^2}\times E[\exp(2cB_s(B_t - B_s))|\mathcal F_s] \times e^{\frac{c(t-s)^4}{4}}
\end{align}

Comment: Your algebra is messed up. You cannot pull out $e^{1+t}$ so the very first step is wrong.

Comment: $\mathbb E[e^{B_s(B_t-B_s)}\mid \mathcal F_s]\neq e^{B_s}\mathbb E[e^{B_t-B_s}\mid \mathcal F_s]$. Moreover, your $\mathbb E[e^{B_t^2}\mid \mathcal F_s]$ should be a $\mathbb E[e^{B_s^2}\mid \mathcal F_s]$ which is indeed $e^{B_s^2}$.

Comment: I don't know if I am mis-reading the definitioin but $EY_t$ seems to be $\infty$ for $t >2$.

Comment: $e^{ab}$ is not $e^{a}e^{b}$. So you cannot separate $B_t^{2}$ from $1+t$.

Comment: This is an exercise from Durrett 7.56 asking to show  $(1+t)^{-1/2}\exp(B^2_t/2(1+t))$ is a martingale. Perhaps there was a typo and he means $(1+t)^{-1/2}\exp(\frac{B^2_t}{2(1+t)})$

Comment: Try to compute $E(e^{cB_t^{2}}|\mathcal F_s)$ for an arbitrary $c >0$. Your computation for the case $c=1$ is not at all useful.

Comment: Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy  I'm having difficulties simplifying particularly for $\mathbb{E}(e^{B_s(B_t-B_s)}\mid \mathcal{F}_s)$